# PHP - HTML best practices to handle (submit) generated rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have `html` table generated via ajax. And last column on this table contains button. My question is what is the best practice to submit these rows (only one at time. I need use this method to amend records). 
Is it worth to wrap each row with

```
<form> 
     <input type="hidden" value="hidden value"> 
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or people using something difference? Reason why i'm asking for is because i'm worry about very long list example `1k` rows or `10k` rows (that means i will have `1k` or `10k` forms on a page).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the amount of forms, the irritation is that a form tag isn't technically allowed between trs (table rows).  To can use ugly table nesting.

Comment: Of course though you can handle it with javascript.  Grab the row, values, and submit one tuple at a time.

Comment: @Progrock Yea i know that but physically it works in tr's.

Comment: 1k -> 10k rows sounds unwieldy.

Comment: show some code of the table, you can build the data structure to be submitted using jQuery and no need to wrap each row  with form tag, and with my suggested approach, you don't need a form tag

Comment: is javascript an option? can you use ajax to send data to php for update? if yes it is not necessary to have a form at all

Comment: @HadiHassan This is nothing what i can show basically is multi row table with 8 columns (just developing structure). And i need to load another page with some existing records (i can pull these records by primary key and some input fields for new data)

Comment: @Klapsius your table contains inputs? or just as `<td> value</td>`

Comment: @LelioFaieta javascript can be a solution but i would like to have another html page with more input's drop downs etc

Comment: @HadiHassan no just a values

Comment: @Klapsius last clarification pls, each row in your table contains one button and when you click it, you want to send the entire row data? or you have one button on the page and when you click it, you want to send the entire rows of the table as variable like array of objects? I didn't understand your given well

Comment: @HadiHassan Each row contains one button and i would like to send one row at the time (probably one hidden input with primary key or i could pick that primary key from column) and then load new page with records by primary key which has been send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
<table id="YourTableId">
    ...
   <tr data-id="yourrowId">
        <td class="col1"> value1</td>
        <td class="col2"> value2</td>
        <td class="col3"> value3</td>
        <td class="actions">
             <a href="#"> Submit</a>
        </td>
   </tr>
   ....
</table>
```

your javascript code will be like

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $('#YourTableId a').off('click').on('click',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr')
          var data={ // here you can add as much as you want from variables
            'id' : tr.data('id), // if you want to send id value
            'col1': tr.find('.col1').text(),
            'col2': tr.find('.col2').text(),
            'col3': tr.find('.col3').text(),
          };

          $.ajax({
              method: 'post',
              url: 'your url goes here',
              data: data,
              success: function(result){
                  // handle the result here
              }
          });
     });
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for an idea. This not working and i think because table is generated via json response? Is it possible?

Comment: then use my code after you generating the table and not on document ready

Comment: if you provide some code of how you are generating the table, I can modify the code to meet your requirements, but I think what I wrote should work but make sure that you add this code after you finish adding the html to the page ( json response  which should be usually through ajax call)

Comment: the function you are using to generate the table and to render its html, when this function finishes its work, after it add the code ( at this point, the table you added is visible to jquery)

Comment: I have no idea how you are generating this table, since you didn't share more code and is this method call on the document ready or on action for example ( click). I hope that elaborate the idea well.

Comment: I must disagree with this solution. While functional, it circumvents the semantics of HTML. A form is a form, a submit button is a submit button. For example, this code assumes the presence of a pointing device. and this data may not be submitted if the user has none.

Comment: @RandomSeed thumbs up for you first, but why you need a form to submit values? no input controls envolved? if you read my comments, I asked the Klapsius if his table contains inputs or not? I would like to hear from you especially I got new information from your answer about the form attribute

Comment: @HadiHassan I stand corrected, I was wrongly assuming the data was entered manualy, not generated. However, I still believe this code is bad form. A `form` is the primary tool for submitting data to a server. For example, a form with `action="POST"` is handled in a particular way by most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a hyperlink (which you can style to look like a button using CSS if you want). e.g:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a>
```

where the value you give as the "id" parameter is the primary key of the record in that row.

Then in edit.php look for the id value using `$_GET["id"]` and fetch the appropriate record from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

[As Progrock advises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590875/php-html-best-practices-to-handle-submit-generated-rows#comment66490893_39590875), a `form` element may only be used "[where flow content is expected](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)" (i.e. not as a direct child of `table` or `tr`).

HTML 5 introduces [a `form` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form) as a workaround:

```
<form id="row_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pk1">
</form>
<form id="row_2">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pk2">
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" name="attribute1" form="row_1"> </td>
        <td> <input type="submit" form="row_1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- and so on for each row -->
</table>
```

---

It has been [brought to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590875/php-html-best-practices-to-handle-submit-generated-rows/39592683#comment66494459_39592105) that in this case, there is no direct user input being submitted, but only generated contents.

Well, then the solution is even simpler:

```
<table>
    <tr> <td>
        <form id="row_1">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pk1">
            <input type="hidden" name="attribute1" value="whatever">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </td> </tr>
    <!-- and so on for each row -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd have a go without form elements, working with editable table cells.  Within each row you provide a button.  And when you click it, an ajax post is made of the cell values.

You could have a non js fall back where the save button is replaced for an edit button that takes you to another page with a single form.

Forgive my JS.

I have the session storage in there just to check the concept.

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

$data = array(
    23 => ['triangle', 'green', '2'],
    47 => ['square', 'red', '3'],
    17 => ['pentagon', 'pink', '4']
);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Save state here
    $_SESSION['submission'] = $_POST;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('button').click(function() {
                    // Get all table cells in the buttons row
                    var $cells = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[contenteditable="true"]');
                    var jsonData = {};
                    $.each($cells, function() {
                        jsonData[get_table_cell_column_class($(this))] = $(this).text().trim();
                    });
                    jsonData['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.post('',jsonData, function() {
                        alert('Saved.');
                    });
                });

                function get_table_cell_column_class($td)
                {
                    var $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index());

                    return $th.attr('class');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="shape">Shape</th>
                    <th class="colour">Colour</th>
                    <th class="width">Width</th>
                    <th>Ops</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($data as $key => $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach($row as $field) { ?>
                            <td contenteditable=true>
                                <?php echo $field ?>
                            </td>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <td>
                            <button id="<?php echo $key ?>">Save</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's before I saw @RandomSeeds approach, which I prefer.